# Navigation property is null when using Include - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api

I'm calling

> Persons.Include(e => e.City)

in "Get()" method in my web API.

The navigation property "ICollection persons" in "City" model return null.
So when I use "PostMan" to get values it throw error

> Could not get any response 
>   There was an error connecting to http://localhost:13236/api/values.

I linked a test project on GitHub : 
https://github.com/MajdAlbaho/SampleWebAPI

Comment: Very incomplete, not answerable.  Edit to include the relvant code in the question, an external link doesn't count.  Also, ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: I Removed the second questions. The link is on get hub and it works

Comment: @MajdAlbaho Please see [mcve] and [ask] amd include relevant code _in the question itself_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable lazy loading `ICollection` property must be marked as `virtual`.
so in your example, instead of:

```
public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

define it like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

This article may be helpful: [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I Really added Virtual to the collection persons as you said but I still have the problem

Comment: What is the problem exactly? is it you can't call your Web API? or you can't load related entities by lazy loading?

Comment: The problem is ICollection<Person> Persons in city model is null and this throw error when I call method Get()

Comment: Make `City` property `virtual` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. :)