# Entity Framework Core get entity without related entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, dbcontext

I've been searching a bit on this but thus far haven't been able to find a decent solution. I'm trying to get an entity from my database without the related entities attached to it.

The function goes as following `return context.Entity.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == name)` where `context is a DbContext`.

As of now the reply contains only one Entity but with an added 50 "child" entities which I do not need.

What would be the best way to go about getting a single entity from the db?

Using `EFC2.1 pre release build`

## Edit:

Also found that if you use `DbContext.Entity.AsNoTracking` you can get the entity without the child collections.

Not sure if the full entity will be saved after making changes and calling `DbContext.saveChanges()`

Comment: In your DbContext constructor : LazyLoading = false;

Comment: @Atlasmaybe Well, the problem is that I do need the connections most of the other times. I just need the single entity without the added entities a couple of times so i'd rather not make that change

Comment: Define your navigation property as virtual to enable lazy loading - **public virtual ICollection<ChildType> NavigationProperty** .

Comment: Then, why not adding another constructor to your DbContext? There's another option like using an anonymous object to query only the wanted object, but it's slighly more complex than adding another constructor...

Comment: @Atlasmaybe Tried it and your answer does indeed work. It enabled me to get the entity without all of the child records. I decided to go with Nish26's comment as the answer though since for me the implementation was slightly easier.

Comment: @Nish26 This did it for me :) Added virtual to the ChildType entity and when I called the function no Child Entities were added to it. If you could add your comment as the answer so I could accept it that would be great

Comment: Why everyone here is speaking about lazy loading while EF Core currently does not support it? Are you using EFC2.1 pre release build?

Comment: @IvanStoev I personally am using the pre release build. I know the current active does not support lazy loading yet untill the update but I don't think it's that far off anymore

Comment: @Haraldur You can use whatever you like. Just when you have question, you should provide the full details. In the case of EF Core the version is very (if not the most) important information.

Comment: @IvanStoev Agreed, edited the title to include 'Core' which I forgot and I'll edit the question to display the current version I'm using. Thanks for the feedback ^^

Comment: See this (answered yesterday) also applicable to EF Core https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841531/6197785

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable Lazy Loading, simply add a property to your class like this.

```
public virtual ICollection<ChildType> NavigationProperty;
```

Here is a very useful document for [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Answer (score 3):

I recently discovered that you can also use `DbContext.Entity.AsNoTracking()` for this purpose.

Using a linq query when fetching an entity will cause all related entities contained in the linq to also be fetched.

Say you have `a Teacher, a Student and a Classroom entity`. A Teacher can have multiple Students and Classrooms. You want to find all Teachers with classroom A and all male students so you would do

```
DbContext.Teachers.Where(x => x.Classroom.Name = "A" && x.Student.Gender = "Male")
```

This will fetch the `Teacher entities` with all underlying `Classrooms` and `Students` since you called on them in the linq expression.
Since you want just the Teacher entity you should use the following :

```
DbContext.Teachers.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Classroom.Name = "A" && x.Student.Gender = "Male")
```

Using `AsNoTracking()` you declare that you do not want the underlying data and just need it to filter through the entity you do want.